# Disambiguating eval, obj (objective), and metric in LightGBM

Tags: r, lightgbm

I'm asking this in reference to the R library `lightgbm` but I think it applies equally to the Python and Multiverso versions.

There are 3 parameters wherein you can choose statistics of interest for your model - `metric`, `eval`, and `obj`. I'm trying to clearly distinguish the different roles of these 3 in plain language.

The documentation says:

> **obj**    objective function, can be character or custom objective function. Examples include regression, regression_l1, huber, binary,
>   lambdarank, multiclass, multiclass
>
> **eval**  evaluation function, can be (list of) character or custom eval function

**metric** had no R documentation, except for the catch all that says "see paraters.md", which also doesn't really explain it, but which lists the following options:

> metric, default={l2 for regression}, {binary_logloss for binary
>   classification},{ndcg for lambdarank}, type=multi-enum,
>   options=l1,l2,ndcg,auc,binary_logloss,binary_error...
>       l1, absolute loss, alias=mean_absolute_error, mae
>       l2, square loss, alias=mean_squared_error, mse
>       l2_root, root square loss, alias=root_mean_squared_error, rmse
>       huber, Huber loss
>       fair, Fair loss
>       poisson, Poisson regression
>       ndcg, NDCG
>       map, MAP
>       auc, AUC
>       binary_logloss, log loss
>       binary_error. For one sample 0 for correct classification, 1 for error classification.
>       multi_logloss, log loss for mulit-class classification
>       multi_error. error rate for mulit-class classification
>       Support multi metrics, separate by , metric_freq, default=1, type=int
>       frequency for metric output is_training_metric, default=false, type=bool
>       set this to true if need to output metric result of training ndcg_at, default=1,2,3,4,5, type=multi-int, alias=ndcg_eval_at,eval_at
>       NDCG evaluation position, separate by ,

My best guess is that

1. `obj` is the objective function of the algorithm, i.e. what it's trying to maximize or minimize, e.g. "regression" means it's minimizing squared residuals
2. `eval` I'm guessing is just one or more additional statistics you'd like to see computed as your algorithm is being fit.
3. `metric` I have no clue how this is used differently than `obj` and `eval`

Comment: See also https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2182#issuecomment-493452818

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have said,

> obj is the objective function of the algorithm, i.e. what it's trying
> to maximize or minimize, e.g. "regression" means it's minimizing
> squared residuals.

Metric and eval are essentially the same. They only really differ in where they are used. Eval is used with the cross-validation method (because it can be used to evaluate the model for early-stopping etc?). [Metric](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Parameters.md#metric-parameters) is used in the normal train situation.

The confusion arises from the influence on several gbm variants (xgboost, lightgbm and sklearn's gbm + maybe an R package) all having slightly differing argument names. For example xgb.cv() in python uses `eval` but for R it uses `metric`. Then in lgbm.cv() for python and R `eval` is used.

I have been very confused switching between xgboost and lightgbm. There is an absolutely amazing [resource by Laurae](https://sites.google.com/view/lauraepp/parameters) that helps you understand each parameter.

Comment: for xgboost classification is the obj/loss function the same?

Comment: Link has been "deactivated"..!

Comment: lightgbm link is also dead